# Translation of simplepicker datetime picker Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker

Im using this plugin: https://priyank-p.github.io/simplepicker/index.html

When i try to translate the name of the months for example, it keeps giving me "NAN" on the date.

Anyone have tried to translate it already? This is one of the lightest plugins that does datetime picker on javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "translate"? Where is your example code?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/priyank-p/simplepicker) does not mention support for locales.

If you want to add translations, you could try the following:

```js
const LOCALES = 'es';

t.months = Array.from({ length: 12 }, (x, i) => new Date(0, i).toLocaleString(LOCALES, { month: 'long' })),
t.days = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (x, i) => new Date(0, 0, i).toLocaleString(LOCALES, { weekday: 'long' }))
```

```js
`<thead>
  <tr>
    ${
      Array.from({ length: 7 }, (x, i) =>
        `<th>${new Date(0, 0, i).toLocaleString(LOCALES, { weekday: 'short' })}</th>`).join('')
    }
  </tr>
</thead>
```

### Example

I could not reverse-engineer the config to pass in the `locales` param, so I just made it a global for the time being.

```js
const LOCALES = 'es';

const main = () => {
  const picker = new SimplePicker('#picker');
  picker.open();
}

/* https://github.com/priyank-p/simplepicker/blob/master/dist/simplepicker.js */
var SimplePicker = function(e) {
  var t = {};

  function i(n) {
    if (t[n]) return t[n].exports;
    var r = t[n] = {
      i: n,
      l: !1,
      exports: {}
    };
    return e[n].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, i), r.l = !0, r.exports
  }
  return i.m = e, i.c = t, i.d = function(e, t, n) {
    i.o(e, t) || Object.defineProperty(e, t, {
      enumerable: !0,
      get: n
    })
  }, i.r = function(e) {
    "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
      value: "Module"
    }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
      value: !0
    })
  }, i.t = function(e, t) {
    if (1 & t && (e = i(e)), 8 & t) return e;
    if (4 & t && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
    var n = Object.create(null);
    if (i.r(n), Object.defineProperty(n, "default", {
        enumerable: !0,
        value: e
      }), 2 & t && "string" != typeof e)
      for (var r in e) i.d(n, r, function(t) {
        return e[t]
      }.bind(null, r));
    return n
  }, i.n = function(e) {
    var t = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
      return e.default
    } : function() {
      return e
    };
    return i.d(t, "a", t), t
  }, i.o = function(e, t) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t)
  }, i.p = "", i(i.s = 0)
}({
  0: function(e, t, i) {
    i("iyB0"), e.exports = i("TYVf")
  },
  "0DyV": function(e, t, i) {
    "use strict";

    function n(e, t) {
      e = [].concat(e);
      for (var i = 0; i < t; i++) e[i] = void 0;
      return e
    }

    function r(e) {
      var i = new Date(e.getTime()),
        r = e.getFullYear(),
        s = e.getMonth(),
        a = {
          date: i,
          month: void 0
        };
      if (t.monthTracker.current = new Date(e.getTime()), t.monthTracker.current.setDate(1), t.monthTracker.years[r] = t.monthTracker.years[r] || {}, void 0 !== t.monthTracker.years[r][s]) return a.month = t.monthTracker.years[r][s], a;
      (e = new Date(e.getTime())).setDate(1), t.monthTracker.years[r][s] = [];
      for (var c = t.monthTracker.years[r][s], o = 0; e.getMonth() === s;) {
        var l = e.getDate(),
          p = e.getDay();
        1 === l && (c[o] = n([], p)), c[o] = c[o] || [], c[o][p] = l, 6 === p && o++, e.setDate(e.getDate() + 1)
      }
      var d = 5;
      void 0 === c[5] && (d = 4, c[5] = n([], 7));
      var m = c[d].length;
      if (m < 7) {
        var u = c[d].concat(n([], 7 - m));
        c[d] = u
      }
      return a.month = c, a
    }
    Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
      value: !0
    }), t.monthTracker = {
      years: {}
    }, t.months = Array.from({ length: 12 }, (x, i) => new Date(0, i).toLocaleString(LOCALES, { month: 'long' })), t.days = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (x, i) => new Date(0, 0, i).toLocaleString(LOCALES, { weekday: 'long' })), t.scrapeMonth = r, t.scrapePreviousMonth = function() {
      var e = t.monthTracker.current;
      if (!e) throw Error("scrapePrevoisMonth called without setting monthTracker.current!");
      return e.setMonth(e.getMonth() - 1), r(e)
    }, t.scrapeNextMonth = function() {
      var e = t.monthTracker.current;
      if (!e) throw Error("scrapePrevoisMonth called without setting monthTracker.current!");
      return e.setMonth(e.getMonth() + 1), r(e)
    };
    var s = {
      st: [1, 21, 31],
      nd: [2, 22],
      rd: [3, 23]
    };
    t.getDisplayDate = function(e) {
      var t = e.getDate();
      return -1 !== s.st.indexOf(t) ? t + "st" : -1 !== s.nd.indexOf(t) ? t + "nd" : -1 !== s.rd.indexOf(t) ? t + "rd" : t + "th"
    }, t.formatTimeFromInputElement = function(e) {
      var t = "",
        i = e.split(":"),
        n = i[0],
        r = (n = +n) >= 12;
      return r && n > 12 && (n -= 12), r || 0 !== n || (n = 12), t += n < 10 ? "0" + n : n, t += ":" + i[1] + " ", t += r ? "PM" : "AM"
    }
  },
  TYVf: function(e, t, i) {
    "use strict";
    var n = i("0DyV"),
      r = i("ht6X"),
      s = new Date,
      a = function() {
        function e(e, t) {
          var i = void 0,
            n = t;
          if ("string" == typeof e) {
            var r = document.querySelector(e);
            if (null === r) throw new Error("Invalid selector passed to SimplePicker!");
            i = r
          } else e instanceof HTMLElement ? i = e : "object" == typeof e && (n = e);
          i || (i = document.querySelector("body")), n || (n = {}), this.selectedDate = new Date, this.injectTemplate(i), this.init(i, n), this.initListeners(), this._eventHandlers = {}, this._validOnListeners = ["submit", "close"]
        }
        return e.prototype.initElMethod = function(e) {
          this.$ = function(t) {
            return e.querySelector(t)
          }, this.$$ = function(t) {
            return e.querySelectorAll(t)
          }
        }, e.prototype.init = function(e, t) {
          this.$simplepickerWrapper = e.querySelector(".simplepicker-wrapper"), this.initElMethod(this.$simplepickerWrapper);
          var i = this.$,
            r = this.$$;
          this.$simplepicker = i(".simpilepicker-date-picker"), this.$trs = r(".simplepicker-calender tbody tr"), this.$tds = r(".simplepicker-calender tbody td"), this.$headerMonthAndYear = i(".simplepicker-month-and-year"), this.$monthAndYear = i(".simplepicker-selected-date"), this.$date = i(".simplepicker-date"), this.$day = i(".simplepicker-day-header"), this.$time = i(".simplepicker-time"), this.$timeInput = i(".simplepicker-time-section input"), this.$timeSectionIcon = i(".simplepicker-icon-time"), this.$cancel = i(".simplepicker-cancel-btn"), this.$ok = i(".simplepicker-ok-btn"), this.$displayDateElements = [this.$day, this.$headerMonthAndYear, this.$date], this.$time.classList.add("simplepicker-fade"), this.render(n.scrapeMonth(s)), t = t || {}, this.opts = t, this.reset(s), void 0 !== t.zIndex && (this.$simplepickerWrapper.style.zIndex = t.zIndex.toString()), t.disableTimeSection && this.disableTimeSection(), t.compactMode && this.compactMode()
        }, e.prototype.reset = function(e) {
          var t = e || new Date;
          this.render(n.scrapeMonth(t));
          var i = t.toTimeString().split(" ")[0].replace(/\:\d\d$/, "");
          this.$timeInput.value = i, this.$time.innerText = n.formatTimeFromInputElement(i);
          var r = t.getDate().toString(),
            s = this.findElementWithDate(r);
          s.classList.contains("active") || (this.selectDateElement(s), this.updateDateComponents(t))
        }, e.prototype.compactMode = function() {
          this.$date.style.display = "none"
        }, e.prototype.disableTimeSection = function() {
          this.$timeSectionIcon.style.visibility = "hidden"
        }, e.prototype.enableTimeSection = function() {
          this.$timeSectionIcon.style.visibility = "visible"
        }, e.prototype.injectTemplate = function(e) {
          var t = document.createElement("template");
          t.innerHTML = r.htmlTemplate, e.appendChild(t.content.cloneNode(!0))
        }, e.prototype.clearRows = function() {
          this.$tds.forEach(function(e) {
            e.innerHTML = "", e.classList.remove("active")
          })
        }, e.prototype.updateDateComponents = function(e) {
          var t = n.days[e.getDay()],
            i = n.months[e.getMonth()] + " " + e.getFullYear();
          this.$headerMonthAndYear.innerHTML = i, this.$monthAndYear.innerHTML = i, this.$day.innerHTML = t, this.$date.innerHTML = n.getDisplayDate(e)
        }, e.prototype.render = function(e) {
          var t = this.$$,
            i = this.$trs,
            n = e.month,
            r = e.date;
          this.clearRows(), n.forEach(function(e, t) {
            var n = i[t].children;
            e.forEach(function(e, t) {
              var i = n[t];
              e ? (i.removeAttribute("data-empty"), i.innerHTML = e) : i.setAttribute("data-empty", "")
            })
          });
          var s = t("table tbody tr:last-child td"),
            a = !0;
          s.forEach(function(e) {
            void 0 === e.dataset.empty && (a = !1)
          });
          var c = s[0].parentElement;
          c.style.display = a && c ? "none" : "table-row", this.updateDateComponents(r)
        }, e.prototype.updateSelectedDate = function(e) {
          var t, i = this.$monthAndYear,
            r = this.$time;
          this.$date;
          t = e ? e.innerHTML.trim() : this.$date.innerHTML.replace(/[a-z]+/, "");
          var s = i.innerHTML.split(" "),
            a = s[0],
            c = s[1],
            o = n.months.indexOf(a),
            l = r.innerHTML.split(":"),
            p = +l[0],
            d = l[1].split(" "),
            m = d[0],
            u = d[1];
          "AM" === u && 12 == p && (p = 0), "PM" === u && p < 12 && (p += 12);
          var h = new Date(+c, +o, +t, +p, +m);
          this.selectedDate = h;
          var v = t + " ";
          v += i.innerHTML.trim() + " ", v += r.innerHTML.trim(), this.readableDate = v.replace(/^\d+/, h.getDate().toString())
        }, e.prototype.selectDateElement = function(e) {
          var t = this.$(".simplepicker-calender tbody .active");
          e.classList.add("active"), t && t.classList.remove("active"), this.updateSelectedDate(e), this.updateDateComponents(this.selectedDate)
        }, e.prototype.findElementWithDate = function(e, t) {
          var i, n;
          return void 0 === t && (t = !1), this.$tds.forEach(function(t) {
            var r = t.innerHTML.trim();
            r === e && (i = t), "" !== r && (n = t)
          }), void 0 === i && t && (i = n), i
        }, e.prototype.handleIconButtonClick = function(e) {
          var t, i = this.$;
          if (e.classList.contains("simplepicker-icon-calender")) {
            var r = i(".simplepicker-icon-time"),
              s = i(".simplepicker-time-section");
            return (c = i(".simplepicker-calender-section")).style.display = "block", s.style.display = "none", r.classList.remove("active"), e.classList.add("active"), void this.toogleDisplayFade()
          }
          if (e.classList.contains("simplepicker-icon-time")) {
            var a = i(".simplepicker-icon-calender"),
              c = i(".simplepicker-calender-section");
            return (s = i(".simplepicker-time-section")).style.display = "block", c.style.display = "none", a.classList.remove("active"), e.classList.add("active"), void this.toogleDisplayFade()
          }
          var o = i(".simplepicker-calender td.active");
          if (o && (t = o.innerHTML.trim()), e.classList.contains("simplepicker-icon-next") && this.render(n.scrapeNextMonth()), e.classList.contains("simplepicker-icon-previous") && this.render(n.scrapePreviousMonth()), t) {
            var l = this.findElementWithDate(t, !0);
            this.selectDateElement(l)
          }
        }, e.prototype.initListeners = function() {
          var e = this,
            t = e.$simplepicker,
            i = e.$timeInput,
            r = e.$ok,
            s = e.$cancel,
            a = e.$simplepickerWrapper,
            c = this;

          function o() {
            c.close(), c.callEvent("close", function(e) {
              e()
            })
          }
          t.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var t = e.target,
              i = t.tagName.toLowerCase();
            e.stopPropagation(), "td" !== i ? "button" === i && t.classList.contains("simplepicker-icon") && c.handleIconButtonClick(t) : c.selectDateElement(t)
          }), i.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
            if ("" !== e.target.value) {
              var t = n.formatTimeFromInputElement(e.target.value);
              c.$time.innerHTML = t, c.updateSelectedDate()
            }
          }), r.addEventListener("click", function() {
            c.close(), c.callEvent("submit", function(e) {
              e(c.selectedDate, c.readableDate)
            })
          }), s.addEventListener("click", o), a.addEventListener("click", o)
        }, e.prototype.callEvent = function(e, t) {
          (this._eventHandlers[e] || []).forEach(function(e) {
            t(e)
          })
        }, e.prototype.open = function() {
          this.$simplepickerWrapper.classList.add("active")
        }, e.prototype.close = function() {
          this.$simplepickerWrapper.classList.remove("active")
        }, e.prototype.on = function(e, t) {
          var i = this._validOnListeners,
            n = this._eventHandlers;
          if (!i.includes(e)) throw new Error("Not a valid event!");
          n[e] = n[e] || [], n[e].push(t)
        }, e.prototype.toogleDisplayFade = function() {
          this.$time.classList.toggle("simplepicker-fade"), this.$displayDateElements.forEach(function(e) {
            e.classList.toggle("simplepicker-fade")
          })
        }, e
      }();
    e.exports = a
  },
  ht6X: function(e, t, i) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
      value: !0
    }), t.htmlTemplate = `\n<div class="simplepicker-wrapper">\n  <div class="simpilepicker-date-picker">\n    <div class="simplepicker-day-header"></div>\n      <div class="simplepicker-date-section">\n        <div class="simplepicker-month-and-year"></div>\n        <div class="simplepicker-date"></div>\n        <div class="simplepicker-select-pane">\n          <button class="simplepicker-icon simplepicker-icon-calender active" title="Select date from calender!"></button>\n          <div class="simplepicker-time">12:00 PM</div>\n          <button class="simplepicker-icon simplepicker-icon-time" title="Select time"></button>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n      <div class="simplepicker-picker-section">\n        <div class="simplepicker-calender-section">\n          <div class="simplepicker-month-switcher simplepicker-select-pane">\n            <button class="simplepicker-icon simplepicker-icon-previous"></button>\n            <div class="simplepicker-selected-date"></div>\n            <button class="simplepicker-icon simplepicker-icon-next"></button>\n          </div>\n          <div class="simplepicker-calender">\n            <table>\n              <thead>\n                <tr>${Array.from({ length: 7 }, (x, i) => `<th>${new Date(0, 0, i).toLocaleString(LOCALES, { weekday: 'short' })}</th>`).join('')}</tr>\n              </thead>\n              <tbody>\n                ` + function(e, t) {
      for (var i = "", n = 1; n <= t; n++) i += e;
      return i
    }("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>", 6) + '\n              </tbody>\n            </table>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class="simplepicker-time-section">\n          <input type="time" value="12:00" autofocus="false">\n        </div>\n      </div>\n      <div class="simplepicker-bottom-part">\n        <button class="simplepicker-cancel-btn simplepicker-btn" title="Cancel">Cancel</button>\n        <button class="simplepicker-ok-btn simplepicker-btn" title="OK">OK</button>\n      </div>\n  </div>\n</div>\n'
  },
  iyB0: function(e, t, i) {}
});
//# sourceMappingURL=simplepicker.js.map

main();
```

```css
/* https://github.com/priyank-p/simplepicker/blob/master/dist/simplepicker.css */

.simplepicker-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #4c4c4c7d;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: none
}

.simplepicker-wrapper.active {
  display: block
}

.simpilepicker-date-picker {
  width: 326px;
  cursor: auto;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 2% auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 1px 2px 4px .5px transparent
}

.simplepicker-day-header {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #016565;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 0
}

.simplepicker-date-section {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #078e8e;
  color: #fff
}

.simplepicker-date-section .simplepicker-month-and-year {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 14px 0 7px;
  font-weight: 200
}

.simplepicker-date-section .simplepicker-date {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 12px
}

.simplepicker-select-pane {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}

.simplepicker-select-pane .simplepicker-time,
.simplepicker-selected-date {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 2
}

.simplepicker-icon,
.simplepicker-selected-date,
.simplepicker-time {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 4px 6px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  opacity: .5
}

.simplepicker-selected-date,
.simplepicker-time {
  opacity: 1
}

.simplepicker-month-switcher {
  margin-top: 5px
}

.simplepicker-icon:hover {
  opacity: .8
}

.simplepicker-icon.active,
.simplepicker-icon:active {
  opacity: 1
}

.simplepicker-icon:focus {
  outline: none
}

.simplepicker-icon-next {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjIiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lY2FwPSJyb3VuZCIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2luPSJyb3VuZCIgY2xhc3M9ImZlYXRoZXIgZmVhdGhlci1hcnJvdy1yaWdodCI+PGxpbmUgeDE9IjUiIHkxPSIxMiIgeDI9IjE5IiB5Mj0iMTIiPjwvbGluZT48cG9seWxpbmUgcG9pbnRzPSIxMiA1IDE5IDEyIDEyIDE5Ij48L3BvbHlsaW5lPjwvc3ZnPg==)
}

.simplepicker-icon-previous {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjIiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lY2FwPSJyb3VuZCIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2luPSJyb3VuZCIgY2xhc3M9ImZlYXRoZXIgZmVhdGhlci1hcnJvdy1sZWZ0Ij48bGluZSB4MT0iMTkiIHkxPSIxMiIgeDI9IjUiIHkyPSIxMiI+PC9saW5lPjxwb2x5bGluZSBwb2ludHM9IjEyIDE5IDUgMTIgMTIgNSI+PC9wb2x5bGluZT48L3N2Zz4=)
}

.simplepicker-icon-calender {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)
}

.simplepicker-icon-time {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IndoaXRlIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjIiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lY2FwPSJyb3VuZCIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2luPSJyb3VuZCIgY2xhc3M9ImZlYXRoZXIgZmVhdGhlci1jbG9jayI+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIiIGN5PSIxMiIgcj0iMTAiPjwvY2lyY2xlPjxwb2x5bGluZSBwb2ludHM9IjEyIDYgMTIgMTIgMTYgMTQiPjwvcG9seWxpbmU+PC9zdmc+)
}

.simplepicker-bottom-part {
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 48%
}

.simplepicker-calender table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px
}

.simplepicker-calender thead th {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  width: 14.28%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center
}

.simplepicker-calender tbody td {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 12px;
  z-index: 1
}

.simplepicker-calender tbody td:after {
  content: " ";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)
}

.simplepicker-calender tbody td:hover:after {
  visibility: visible
}

.simplepicker-calender tbody td.active,
.simplepicker-calender tbody td:active {
  color: #fff
}

.simplepicker-calender tbody .active:after,
.simplepicker-calender tbody td:active:after {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: teal;
  z-index: -1
}

.simplepicker-calender tbody td[data-empty] {
  pointer-events: none
}

.simplepicker-time-section {
  display: none;
  height: 120px
}

.simplepicker-time-section input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  max-width: 120px;
  max-height: 32px;
  padding: 4px 3px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  margin: 25% auto
}

.simplepicker-time-section input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom-color: teal
}

.simplepicker-picker-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.simplepicker-btn {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-color: #016565;
  color: #016565;
  font-size: 13px
}

.simplepicker-btn:active,
.simplepicker-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #016565
}

.simplepicker-fade {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 88%, .95)
}

.simplepicker-btn,
.simplepicker-icon,
.simplepicker-wrapper {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/priyank-p/simplepicker/master/dist/simplepicker.js"></script>
<div id="picker"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. I will give it a try and i will come back telling you the result! Wonderful solution.